# How to create a nested-list of categories in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, nested-lists

How can I create a nested list of categories in Laravel?

I want to create something like this:

- --- **Php**
- ------ Laravel
- --------- Version
- ------------ V 5.7
- --- **Python**
- ------ Django
- --- **Ruby**
- ..........

The fields of my categories table are:

```
id | name | parent_id
```

> If I have to add another column like depth or something, please tell me.

I am using this following code, but I think it is not the best solution. Besides, I can not pass this function to my view.

```
function rec($id)
{
     $model = Category::find($id);
     foreach ($model->children as $chield) rec($chield->id);
     return $model->all();
}

function main () {
    $models = Category::whereNull('parent_id')->get();
    foreach ($models as $parent) return rec($parent->id);
}
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can make a self-referential model:

```
class Category extends Model {

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Category', 'parent_id');
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Category', 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

and make a recursive relation:

```
// recursive, loads all descendants
public function childrenRecursive()
{
   return $this->children()->with('childrenRecursive');
}
```

and to get parents with all their children:

```
$categories = Category::with('childrenRecursive')->whereNull('parent_id')->get();
```

Lastly you need to just iterate through the children until children is null. There can definitely be some performance issues with this if you are not careful. If this is a fairly small dataset that you plan to remain that way it shouldn't be an issue. If this is going to be an ever growing list it might make sense to have a `root_parent_id` or something to query off of and assemble the tree manually.

Comment: This is awesome, thx :) The architecture is very good, definitely helps preserve memory

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: @AlexHarris How can we do pagination with nested category?

Comment: how do u loop through this the most efficient way in blade?  say to just make a nested ```<ul>``` thanks in advance. btw this is an awesome idea!

Answer (score 3):

If someone needs a better answer look up my answer, it helped me, when I had faced with such a problem.

```
   class Category extends Model {

     private $descendants = [];

     public function subcategories()
        {
          return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id');
        }

     public function children()
        {
            return $this->subcategories()->with('children');
        }

     public function hasChildren(){
            if($this->children->count()){
                return true;
            }
    
            return false;
        }

     public function findDescendants(Category $category){
            $this->descendants[] = $category->id;
    
            if($category->hasChildren()){
                foreach($category->children as $child){
                    $this->findDescendants($child);
                }
            }
        }
    
      public function getDescendants(Category $category){
            $this->findDescendants($category);
            return $this->descendants;
        }
 }
```

And In your Controller just test this:

```
$category = Category::find(1);
$category_ids = $category->getDescendants($category);
```

It will result ids in array all descendants of your category where id=1.
then :

```
$products = Product::whereIn('category_id',$category_ids)->get();
```

You are welcome =)

Comment: In your code you are having:  return $this->subcategories()->with('children'), yet, you dont have any method subcategories(). 
Either you borrowed the code from someone or this will break.

Comment: @Vladd Thank you for your attention. I updated my answer : added relational function subcategories(). If you facing with problems in relationships, you may read more about Laravel's relationships https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: i am not facing any problems. Just pointed out that your code is incomplete, and therefore should not be posted, I did not even try it as just by reading i saw it will not work. 
My warm advise is not to post things that are not checked 3 times and not complete.

Comment: Also, to make it complete, i would add a methods that would help in real life, such as to find a top level parent of any category, to create a breadcrumbs, etc.. then your post would stand out.

Comment: @Vladd, i think it is not necessary, stackoverflow is not learning resource. My aim wasn't make full functionality, the need was to answer to question.

Comment: Working like butter :) good good job man.

Answer (score 3):

This function will return tree array:

```
function getCategoryTree($parent_id = 0, $spacing = '', $tree_array = array()) {
    $categories = Category::select('id', 'name', 'parent_id')->where('parent_id' ,'=', $parent_id)->orderBy('parent_id')->get();
    foreach ($categories as $item){
        $tree_array[] = ['categoryId' => $item->id, 'categoryName' =>$spacing . $item->name] ;
        $tree_array = $this->getCategoryTree($item->id, $spacing . '--', $tree_array);
    }
    return $tree_array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Searching for something somehow in this area I wanted to share a functionality for getting the depth level of child:

```
    function getDepth($category, $level = 0) {
    if ($category->parent_id>0) {
        if ($category->parent) {
                $level++;
                return $this->getDepth($category->parent, $level);
            }
        }
       return $level;
    }
```

Maybe it will help someone!
Cheers!

Comment: also ```$loop->depth()``` when using recursive ```foreach```

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this problem like this :

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function categories()
    {
       return $this->hasMany(Category::class);
    }

    public function childrenCategories()
    {
       return $this->hasMany(Category::class)->with('categories');
    }

}
```

and get category with children like this :

```
Category::whereNull('category_id')
    ->with('childrenCategories')
    ->get();
```

notice : just rename parent_id column to category_id

Answer (score -1):

This also worked:

**View:**

```
    $traverse = function ($categories) use (&$traverse) {
        foreach ($categories as $category) $traverse($cat->Children);
    };
    $traverse(array ($category));
```

**Model:**

```
public function Children()
{
    return $this->hasMany($this, 'parent');
}

public function Parent()
{
    return $this->hasOne($this,'id','parent');
}
```