# Laravel - How to get all nested subcategories recursively

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get IDs of all nested sub-categories.

The database tables are following

```
categories

id | name       | parent_id 
-----------------------------
1  | Electronics| null  
2  | media      | 1
3  | Clothing   | null  
4  | Craft      | null
5  | Mens       | 3
6  | Women      | 3
7  | Shirt      | 5
8  | Jeans      | 5
9  | speaker    | 2
10 | DVDs       | 2
11 | Computers  | 1
```

Lets i have a Category `Electronics`, My task is to get IDs of its sub-categories and deep down to last level of it.
I am trying the following

**Category model**

```
public function subCategory(){
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id');
}

public function recursiveChildren()
{
    return $this->subCategory()->with('recursiveChildren');
}
```

**ProductController**

```
$cate_id        = 1 // Electronics
$categoriesID   = Category::with('recursiveChildren')->where('id', $cat_id)->pluck("id");
echo '<pre>'; print_r($categoriesID); die;
```

I am getting follwing result:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
        )

)
```

I want to achieve following:

```
Array(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 9
    [3] => 10
)
```

Please correct me. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research I have found the solution

---

**Category Model**

```
public function subcategories(){
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id');
}

public function children(){
    return $this->subcategories()->with('children');
}

public function hasChildren(){
    if($this->children->count()){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public function findDescendants(Category $category){
    $this->descendants[] = $category->id;

    if($category->hasChildren()){
        foreach($category->children as $child){
            $this->findDescendants($child);
        }
    }
}

public function getDescendants(Category $category){
    $this->findDescendants($category);
    return $this->descendants;
}
```

**Controller**

```
$category = Category::find($cat_id);
$category_ids = $category->getDescendants($category);
echo '<pre>'; print_r($categoriesID); die;
```

I have found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43989728/how-to-create-a-nested-list-of-categories-in-laravel/49845103#49845103)

Comment: nice - won't this add the parent ID as one of the descendents though?

Answer (score 1):

It can be tricky to this manually. You'll bounce between "it works but it's slow" and "it's fast... but it doesn't work anymore".

You best bet is to use this wonderful package https://github.com/staudenmeir/laravel-adjacency-list. It adds several relationships that uses CTE queries, which are far too complex to be described in a few words here (and are off topic) but pretty useful when it comes to recursion.

The good news is that with this package, all this is pretty simple.

From the documentation:

> #### Included Relationships
>
> The trait provides various relationships:
>
> - ancestors(): The model's recursive parents.
> - ancestorsAndSelf(): The
>   model's recursive parents and itself.
> - children(): The model's direct
>   children.
> - childrenAndSelf(): The model's direct children and itself.
> - descendants(): The model's recursive children. descendantsAndSelf():
>   The model's recursive children and itself.
> - parent(): The model's
>   direct parent.
> - parentAndSelf(): The model's direct parent and itself.
> - rootAncestor(): The model's topmost parent. siblings(): The parent's
>   other children.
> - siblingsAndSelf(): All the parent's children.

---

If you want to learn more on this topic, you can check this package, https://github.com/staudenmeir/laravel-cte, by the same author, which is a dependency of the previous one.

Another reading on CTE queries: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-recursive-cte-common-table-expressions/

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have managed to find solution