# Filter Laravel Collections by Category Hierarchy

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on a Laravel project where I have a hierarchical category structure. Each collection in my database is associated with a category, and this category can have parent and child categories. I'm trying to implement a filter functionality that allows me to retrieve collections based on a selected category and all its subcategories.

For example, if I select the "Music" category, I want to retrieve all collections within the "Music" category, as well as collections in its subcategories like "Rock," "Hip-Hop," and "Rap."

I've tried to implement a scope method in my Eloquent model to achieve this, but I'm encountering issues with recursion and the relationships between categories.

Here's my current code:

```
 public function scopeOfCategory($query, $category){
    if ($category) {
        return $query->where(function ($query) use ($category) {
            $query
                ->where('category_id', $category)
                ->orWhereHas('category.parent', function ($query) use ($category) {
                    $query->ofCategory($category);
                });
        });
    }
    return $query;
}
```

error:

```
local.ERROR: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::ofCategory()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a nested-list of categories in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43989728/how-to-create-a-nested-list-of-categories-in-laravel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works this way, but I don't think it's a good way, anyway it worked :)

```
public function getChildreenIdByCategory($category_id)
{
    $childreen_ids = [$category_id];
    $childreen = categories::where('parent_id', $category_id)->get();
    foreach ($childreen as $child) {
        $childreen_ids[] = $child->id;
        $childreen_ids = array_merge(
            $childreen_ids,
            $this->getChildreenIdByCategory($child->id)
        );
    }
    return $childreen_ids;
}
public function scopeOfCategory($query, $category)
{
    if ($category) {
        $ids = $this->getChildreenIdByCategory($category);
        return $query->whereIn('category_id', $ids);
    }
}
```

Comment: Mark as an answer please.